# VirtualBOXの共有フォルダ上にvirtualenv環境が作成できない。

Tags: virtualbox, python3

お世話になっております。
この環境でVirtualBOX上にCentOS 7をインストールし、VirtualBOXの共有フォルダ上にvirtualenvコマンドによる環境を作成したところ、read onlyによるエラーとなります。
作業ユーザはvboxsfグループに属しており、通常のディレクトリ/ファイル作成は可能です。
これは対応可能でしょうか。

```
[user@localhost ~]$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),983(vboxsf)
[user@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
[user@localhost ~]$ df -h /media/sf_sh
ファイルシス   サイズ  使用  残り 使用% マウント位置
sh               109G  102G  6.6G   94% /media/sf_sh
```

本ディレクトリがVirtualBOXの共有フォルダです。

```
[user@localhost ~]$ mkdir /media/sf_sh/perm_test
[user@localhost ~]$ echo "test" > /media/sf_sh/perm_test/perm_test.log
[user@localhost ~]$ ls -l /media/sf_sh/perm_test
合計 1
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 5  2月 20 23:33 perm_test.log
[user@localhost ~]$ cat /media/sf_sh/perm_test/perm_test.log
test
[user@localhost ~]$ rm -rf /media/sf_sh/perm_test
```

ディレクトリ/ファイル作成可能です。

```
[user@localhost ~]$ virtualenv /media/sf_sh/perm_test
Using base prefix '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0'
New python executable in /media/sf_sh/perm_test/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /media/sf_sh/perm_test/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1370, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'python3.6' -> '/media/sf_sh/perm_test/bin/python'
```

エラーとなります。

```
[user@localhost ~]$ ls -ld /media/sf_sh/perm_test
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0  2月 20 23:34 /media/sf_sh/perm_test
[user@localhost ~]$ ls -l /media/sf_sh/perm_test
合計 0
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0  2月 20 23:34 bin
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0  2月 20 23:34 include
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 0  2月 20 23:34 lib
```

一部フォルダ/ファイルは作成されているようです。

```
[user@localhost ~]$ virtualenv perm_test
Using base prefix '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0'
New python executable in /home/user/perm_test/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /home/user/perm_test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[user@localhost ~]$
```

共有でないフォルダでは成功します。

<2017/02/26追記>
各バージョンは以下のとおりです。
VirtualBox: 5.111.14 r112924(Qt5.6.2)
ホストOS  : Windows10 Pro 64bit
ゲストOS  : CentOS 7.3(1611)

Comment: 探してみたところ、virtualbox のバージョンによっては symlink が作成できないという記述もあるようですが、virtualbox のバージョンはいくつでしょうか? またホスト OS は何でしょうか?

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。末尾に追記したとおり、それぞれ5.111.14、Win10proです。

Comment: [このページ](http://qiita.com/tanakachang/items/11dab5309b64b4f64119)に、Windows ホストの場合にシンボリックリンクが作れない時の対処方法があるようです。この方法で起動した virtualbox 内だといかがでしょうか?

Comment: 教えていただいた方法で解決しました！